# Can I sync podcasts from the iPhone to my PC's iTunes? (not the other way around)

Tags: iphone, itunes, podcasts

Back in the iPod days, I used to download podcasts in my PC with iTunes, then sync them to the iPod. Now that I use an iPhone, I download the podcasts directly on the phone, but I'd like to sync them back to the PC with iTunes, in order to have a backup. Can iTunes actually do that?

I am asking this because I have the "Sync podcasts" option turned on both on iTunes and in the iPhone, and up to now I thought it did exactly that, but today I needed to delete some podcasts from my phone to free up space, and I went looking at my PC's iTunes library and found out that it actually didn't have any of those old episodes. So... the "Sync podcasts" option in iTunes, is it only one way? (PC ->iPhone)